# People Picker Apply to each Creating multiple entries when Copying to separate list

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, people-picker, person-or-group

The problem I have is, I have a flow that triggers when and item is created. This flow copies items to another list.
The items it copies over

- single line test fields
- Multi line text fields
- People Picker single selection
- People picker multi selection
- Attachments

All items make it over properly except for the Multi line people picker.  Initially it would wrap the multi people picker in the apply to each (for each loop). If there was more than one email it would run the flow multiple times causing multiple entries on the destination list. I was able to solve this by adding the initialize and set variable actions.

At first I had it set as a string taking the create item out of the apply to each loop but it would combine the emails in to one causing the people picker not to be able to distinguish between the emails giving an error message that it can not find the user  .
Example: The emails entered in the people picker are ABC@123.com and DEF@123.com. Flow errors output ABC@123.comDEF@123.com.

Or when I try to enter an delineator like a semi colon it adds it to the end of the email saying ABC@123.com;DEF@123.com;  Could not be found still looking at is as one ling string.

I fixed this by initializing and setting the variable again but setting it as an array. The output would separate the entries as it should.  it would recognize the multiple emails and individuals i.e. "ABC@123.com", "DEF@123.com". But it still gives me the message that it couldn't find the users.

The out come I'm looking for is for it to see the emails as individuals  in the people picker > Copy over to list2 people picker so it can generate an email using those emails addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps for copying multiple selection person or group column values from one list to another list:

1. Add "Initialize variable" action with array variable
2. Add "Apply to each" action with multiple selection person or group column and inside loop add "Append to array variable" action in below format:

   [image]
3. Then use this array variable inside Create item or update item action (for list 2) as per your requirements:

   [image]

**Reference**: [Copying Multiple Choice & Person Picker Fields Between Lists](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Copying-Multiple-Choice-amp-Person-Picker-Fields-Between-Lists/td-p/639510)